# How would I connect these parts in a non destructive way?

Tags: topology

[image]

I want to connect those rounded edges to the ngon next to them in a non-destructive way. This is my low poly model, and I want to connect them so that I can subdivide this model heavily and sculpt on it. The image below is what I tried to do by simply adding loopcuts to connect them.

[image: I tried to add loopcuts here to connect them]

The only problem is that when I subdivide it, it creates horrible topology that is very difficult to work with:

[image: You can see how everything is uneven]

So does anyone know how I would connect these to obtain good topology when subdividing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.

You can add the green cuts in the below picture to support your geometry better along the horizontal axis. That would maintain a nicer grid pattern in subdivision. You may also choose to delete the cuts marked in red if you want to maintain all quads, though triangles might not even cause much of a problem in this case.

[image: Picture from OP with additional loop cuts marked in green]

Note though that for sculpting this most likely doesn't really matter either way. In sculpting you will deform your high density mesh in all kinds of weird ways and in most cases you'll have to do a retopology pass in the end anyways if you want nice elegant and/or performant geometry. This might not be true for your particular usecase, but usually that is how it works.